# How to generate Unix Epoch timestamp (13 digits) with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, timestamp, epoch

I generated my timestamp using PowerShell below:

```
(Get-Date -UFormat %s).Substring(0,14) -replace("\.","")
```

However the result is not matching (it only match for first 4 digits) with the timestamp at https://currentmillis.com/ or by calling `Date.now()` in Javascript.

Is it possible to do it with PowerShell?

Comment: You've got a PowerShell example further down on that site you're linking to; `[DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`

Comment: @notjustme I am a dub